# How do you run eslint for only a specific rule or set of rules - command line only

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I know you can define rules in an `.eslintrc` file, but what if I just want to run `eslint` and check for one specific rule?

E.g. `$ eslint helpme.js --rule some-important-rule`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but I was able to get this working:

`$ eslint helpme.js --no-eslintrc --env "es6" --env "node" --parser-options "{ecmaVersion: 2018}" --rule "{some-important-rule: error}"`

**Note**: With this method (ignoring `.eslintrc` completeley) you still have to add some stuff from `.eslintrc` like your environment and parser options.

Comment: According to the docs, you should only need the "--rule" part: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface#--rule

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use your .eslintrc file to keep your configuration (parser, plugin settings, etc), you can use [eslint-nibble](https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble) with the `--rule=some-important-rule` flag.  This will respect your normal configuration, but only show you errors from that rule.  There are some other flags as well like `--no-interactive` if you want to run this in something like a CI environment.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of eslint-nibble.

Comment: Love this! eslint-nibble is exactly the workflow I was looking to achieve coming to this question!

Comment: Indeed a great tool, but is there a way to only output the errors and not the warnings

Comment: @shevisitamid yes you can use the `--no-warnings` flag: https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble#--no-warnings

Comment: eslint-nibble seems like a nice solution, but I don't understand why ESLint doesn't work this way by default :\ If an `.eslintrc.js` exists, when would someone use `--rule` without `--no-eslintrc`? And dropping things like the `parser` setting from `--no-eslintrc` seems to mess things up, no (which I suppose is part of the motivation behind eslint-nibble)?

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on @matrik answer, this doesn't require me to define all eslint config again and also shows the file name.

```
eslint helpme.js | egrep "react/jsx-no-literals" -B 1
```

Comment: That shows the preceding line, which might just be another error instead of the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ESLint custom formatter](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/working-with-custom-formatters).

It can be used to filter part of rules, files you want to pay attention to.

And you don't need to :

- Edit your ESLint config file.
- Use complicate command.

#### DEMO for filter files contain error which rules id is `prop-types`:

```js
// ./eslint-file-path-formatter.js
const fs = require('fs');

function containRules(result, targetRuleId) {
  if (!result || !targetRuleId) {
    return false;
  }

  return result.messages.some((cur) => {
    // console.log(`cur?.ruleId = ${cur?.ruleId}`);
    if (cur?.ruleId?.includes(targetRuleId)) {
      return true;
    }
  });
}

module.exports = function (results, context) {
  const summary = [];
  results.forEach((cur) => {
    if (containRules(cur, 'prop-types')) {
      summary.push(`'${cur.filePath}',`);
    }
  });

  // fs.writeFileSync('eslint-error-files.txt', summary.join('\n'));
  // return 'Done Write';

  return summary.join('\n');
};
```

#### Usage:

```bash
eslint . -f ./eslint-file-path-formatter.js
```

Then this formatter will print all files name to console.

You can also write result to local files, do whatever you want.

Comment: Link returns a 404. Looks like you dropped an "s" on the url: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/working-with-custom-formatters

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to see single rule output while still using `.eslintrc` is to use grep:

```
$ eslint helpme.js | egrep "(^/|some\-important\-rule$)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of running eslint only for linebreak style (CRLF or LF) rule using eslint flat config.
In my project i've created file `<project-folder>\eslint-single-configs\eslint.linebreaks.config.mjs`, which content is:

```
import globals from 'globals'
import ts from 'typescript-eslint'
import stylistic from '@stylistic/eslint-plugin'

export default [
  {
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 'latest',
      sourceType: 'module',
      globals: {
        ...globals.serviceworker,
        ...globals.browser,
      },
      parser: ts.parser,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        sourceType: 'module',
        ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true,
        }
      },
    },
    files: ['**/*.{ts,cts,mts,tsx,d.ts,js,cjs,mjs,jsx}'],
    plugins: {
      '@stylistic/js': stylistic,
    },
    rules: {
      '@stylistic/js/linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    },
  },
  // !!! 'ignores' must be in a standalone object to work globally
  {
    ignores: ['dist', 'dev-dist', 'eslint.config.mjs'],
  }
]
```

I've not extended any config and have defined single rule.

Then in package.json i've added scripts:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {    
    "lint-linebreak": "eslint . --no-config-lookup --config eslint-single-configs/eslint.linebreaks.config.mjs --max-warnings 0",
    "lint-linebreak-fix": "eslint . --fix --no-config-lookup --config eslint-single-configs/eslint.linebreaks.config.mjs --max-warnings 0",
  }
}
```

And run them with `yarn run lint-linebreak` or `yarn run lint-linebreak-fix`

For it to work, you need install
`yarn add --dev eslint globals typescript-eslint @stylistic/eslint-plugin`
Maybe you also need `yarn add --dev @eslint/js`, not sure which libs are necessary for this config.